# passing arguments to constructor violates encapsulation?

Tags: oop

Incapsulation:

> - language mechanism for restricting direct access to some of the    object's components.
> - A language construct that facilitates the    bundling of data with the methods operating on that data.

```
class Cat
{
    private string catName;
    private CatBreed catBreed;

    public Cat(string name, CatBreed breed)
    {
        catName = name;
        catBreed = breed;
    }

    // methods that use catName and catBreed fields
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
var cat = new Cat("Thomas", CatBreed.Abyssinian);
...
```

Colleagues tried to convince that passing arguments to constructor violates encapsulation because external system knows about Cat class internal implementation. They are rigtht?

Answer (score 0):

What does the constructors parameters tell any external system about the classes implemtation?
Sounds like nonsense to me.